Apex - how to hide cols in interactive report using css static file
I want to hide some columns in an interactive report based on the user logged in. I have difference CSS files for different types of user assigned to Theme Styles. In my CSS file, I have the following:
` .orange_item{
    background-color:orange;
    }
    #ON_LEAVE, /*header*/
    td[headers="ON_LEAVE"]/*rows*/
    {
       display:none;
    }`

This code works when I place the code directly in the inline css at page level of the report but does not work when I put it in a CSS file. (The app IS picking up the css file as other classes eg css class .orange_item is working correctly).   How/where do I reference #ON_LEAVE in the interactive report?  Thanks for any help you can provide

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
